# SSRS Report builder and MySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report builder report.  The query below will not yield any results.  However when i run this query outside SSRS against my MySQL DB I get the results i want.

Thanks
Kenny

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr.user_name, COUNT(aud.user_id) AS audit_totals_total
FROM prover.aud_results_v AS aud
JOIN prover.user_profiles AS usr ON aud.user_id = usr.user_id
WHERE (aud.aud_date = @startdate AND aud.aud_time > '17:59:59' OR aud.aud_date = @enddate2 AND aud.aud_time < '06:00:00')

GROUP BY aud.user_id
ORDER BY usr.user_name
```

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't it called **SQL Server** Reporting Services?

Comment: Can you say whether you're using integrated authentication or credentials stored with the report?

Comment: I am using a data source stored on a Sharepoint site that has the connection settings